# How to get strings with specific length from NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, fast-enumeration

I want to get strings that have specific length in NSArray.

The array has many elements and I don't want to use fast enumeration.

Is there a possible way?

Comment: No matter how you do it you'll get the same function "under the covers" -- iterate through the array and test the individual strings for their length.  Using something like filteredArrayWithPredicate might save a few cycles vs doing it in the straight-forward fashion, or might be slower, hard to predict.

Comment: (Of course you could always keep separately some sort of list of string lengths, and search that.  But then there's the overhead of preparing the list.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works like a charm:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.length == %d", lenght];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you do you will be using fast enumeration whether you realize it or not.  However, have you considered using an NSPredicate object and the `filteredArrayWithPredicate` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *yourArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Apple, Orange, Grapes, Cherry, nil"];

for(NSString *element in yourArray){

    if(element.length==yourLength){
        [filteredArray addObject:element];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Filtered array now contains the elements with length %d", yourLength);
NSLog(@"Filtered array--%@", filteredArray);
```

Comment: Hey, I said i don't want to use fast enumeration.

Comment: See @borrrden's answer, even my answer (which you accepted) uses fast enumeration under the hood.